# UDK - Packaging the Game

Tags: udk, distribution

I have set up all the config files to my game classes and am able to launch the game to test everything.

Although when I package the game, it still runs the UT deathmatch game??

What other lines in the config files should be changed to make it default to my game and default map once published?